# How do I display a JS variable's value on an HTML webpage?

Tags: javascript, html

I am attempting to make a competitive analysis scouting app for robotics, and I want to display the values of some JS variable I've made. I tried using `.innerHTML`, but that just displayed the variable's name. This is the code I have to display the variable:

```
document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML = "linesCrossed";
```

I am also doing this in electron, so maybe that's part of the issue?
Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: remove the quotation marks?

Comment: "linesCrossed" is a string. If it is a variable name, use it without quotations. Why did you use the quotation marks in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest trying the following, which has `linesCrossed` without quotes:

```
<script> document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML = linesCrossed;</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using a [*string literal*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) i.e. "linesCrossed". To reference the variable, remove the quotes.

```js
var linesCrossed = 1337;
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
  document.addEventListener("click", function(clickEvent) {
    if (clickEvent.target.id == 'updateButton') {
      document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML = linesCrossed;
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<div>P1:
  <span id="p1"></span>
</div>
<button id="updateButton">update p1</button>
```

The code sample above uses *event delegation*, utilizing the [event.target](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target) property of the click event.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display the value of a variable, you should not wrap it with single quotations `'`, double quotations `"` or backticks `` ` ``.

```
document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML = linesCrossed;
```